# Number of people chatting

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

I know it's a small thing but to suggest there's 24 people chatting in the Ask Ubuntu rooms is misleading.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Since the move to chat.se it reports the number of people chatting on the chat.se server. Not sure if that's going to change because of how the Chat API works

Answer (score 2):

This is by design, as we want natural cross-pollination between all "family" websites.

So when you see 24 people chatting, it means 24 people chatting at http://chat.stackexchange.com and you might find interesting people or topics you wouldn't otherwise have found.

And of course **the chat house ad *does* show how many people are in just the site-specific rooms** as well, so it's accurate in both dimensions.

Comment: Since this is by design, I'll take the opportunity to do something I've always wanted to do as a mod for soooo long: use the `status-bydesign` tag!